# TypeError: $(...) is null: Why?

Tags: jquery

At the moment I am trying to migrate an old Joomla 1.6 template to the new version 3.3
But this isn't an issue. I am not a jQuery neither JS professional, so I am a bit lost with this problem.

The problem I have is that I don't understand, why I got this error (showing up in my firebug):

```
TypeError: $(...) is null
http://joomla3.mypage.de/
Line 109
```

This is the new template where the above error occurs:
http://joomla3.mypage.de/

The old template works fine as you can see (**no JS errors**):
http://www.mypage.de/index.php/de/

Many thanks for help.

Selim

---

Many thanks for the prompt replies!

I removed the broken script-path. But still doesn't work
for:
http://joomla3.mypage.de/

The thing is: if you look here:
http://www.mypage.de/index.php/de/

although there is also the same "404 for jquery-1.3.2.min.js"
it works all the same!

What can I do?

Thank you!

Comment: First error in the console is a 404 for jquery-1.3.2.min.js

Comment: please consider your mess with the included jQuery-Versions and other scripts and try to tidy up.

Comment: Maybe you have an idea what I can do for tiding my jQuery versions? Which lines should I remove? Which shall I keep?

Comment: You've removed your customer's name from the links - now they dont work (That someone is paying you to do this work is truly worrying)

Comment: Sorry. It was a matter of desperate search for an answer after seraching for 5 hours. You know these cases. Since we coulnd't manage to find a solution, it is not useful anymore, is it?
Secondly the two links are obsolete in future anyway. I do apologize for that as it was an act of desperation. Thank you Jamiec and all for your help. I do really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

You've included many versions of jquery. One is returning http 404 not found

This line is first - jQuery 1.11. Thats a reasonable version

`<script src="/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

This line is later - jQuery 1.4.2 very old version

`<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/templates/rogenwieserjoomlatemplate/js/jquery.js"></script>`

Then you've got this later on. jQuery 1.3 but its a 404

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>`

The very first error in the console says it all

> "NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://joomla3.mypage.de/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know what I can do about it / don't understand your answer. Very sorry!

Can you give me an idea what I should remove and what I should add?

Many thanks for further help!

Selim

Comment: You probably want to remove the second two and leave the first one I indicated in my answer. The first is the highest version of jQuery.

Comment: I tried removing the second one. But now the whole bgimage is gone.

Comment: @Selim - Im sorry, but this is called debugging and I'm afraid you're going to have to do that yourself, nobody here can answer why your website does not work, we can only help with specific problems.

Comment: Yes, of course. I can understand. And I am very very glad you could give me all these helpful support. Thank you.